# How do I add particles around objects

Tags: particles

In this picture, I modelled a very (bad) gravestone. What I want is described below. Would really appreciate it if you could explain it simply. I'm new to blender. Also, is there an addon for it?
[image: )]
I want weeds only around the stone slab not inside it (which happens if I use vertex groups

[image]

This is the best reference image I could find that resembles what I want. Notice how the grass clumps around the roadsign.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes getting out of a box is the easiest solution. I would create new object to emit those particles ;)